# From .ui to .py : pyside-uic not working

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I cannot convert my .ui file from Qt Designer to a .py file with the PySide scritp : pyside-uic.exe

I get this error :

[image]
Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have the answer now, I was using both PyQT4 and Pyside as librairies for my interface. The problem is that some librairies are not compatible with both librairies (like PyQwt). So, it's really important to choose weather you use PyQt or Pyside for your interface.